# Importing an S3 storage via amplify CLI for Android project throws 403 unauthenticated error while trying to upload file to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

When I create s3 from amplify CLI using: amplify add storage .. everything works fine and I can upload files.
But importing an existing S3 bucket via amplify import storage in CLI and uploading the file to S3 is throwing me the below error,

```
2021-02-06 11:39:26.571 16838-16838/com.example.seki E/MyAmplifyApp: Upload failed
    StorageException{message=Something went wrong with your AWS S3 Storage upload file operation, cause=com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: AE9D3FCEA04F4A6B), S3 Extended Request ID: el6xSv6LQmsoV+JxPAiKy92Qmh5opEARO6RIhQLISz+vHBxp83+uY6jmLyQP8GXlrdDdhJoCTrY=, recoverySuggestion=See attached exception for more information and suggestions}
        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.operation.AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation$UploadTransferListener.onError(AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation.java:207)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferStatusUpdater$4.run(TransferStatusUpdater.java:306)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: AE9D3FCEA04F4A6B), S3 Extended Request ID: el6xSv6LQmsoV+JxPAiKy92Qmh5opEARO6RIhQLISz+vHBxp83+uY6jmLyQP8GXlrdDdhJoCTrY=
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:420)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:229)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4913)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1960)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:282)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:114)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2021-02-06 11:39:26.574 16838-16838/com.example.seki E/MyAmplifyApp: Upload failed
    StorageException{message=Storage upload operation was interrupted., cause=null, recoverySuggestion=Please verify that you have a stable internet connection.}
        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.operation.AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation$UploadTransferListener.onStateChanged(AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation.java:188)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferStatusUpdater$2.run(TransferStatusUpdater.java:224)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Note : I enable unauthenticated access for the Cognito identity pool created when importing S3.

I have raised the same in amplify Github as well, - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6515